# PRove this Inequality $4(\sqrt{a^3b^3}+\sqrt{b^3c^3}+\sqrt{c^3a^3})\leq 4c^3+(a+b)^3$

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c$ are non-negative numbers. Prove that

$$4(\sqrt{a^3b^3}+\sqrt{b^3c^3}+\sqrt{c^3a^3})\leq 4c^3+(a+b)^3$$

---

$\Leftrightarrow -\left (\sqrt{a^3}+\sqrt{b^3}-2\sqrt{c^3} \right )^2 - 3ab \left (\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b} \right )^2 \le 0$

I need a new method that more clearly than this

Answer (score 0):

It's $$4c^3-4(\sqrt{a^3}+\sqrt{b^3})\sqrt{c^3}+(a+b)^3-4\sqrt{a^3b^3}\geq0,$$ which is a quadratic inequality of $\sqrt{c^3}.$

Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$4(\sqrt{a^3}+\sqrt{b^3})^2-4((a+b)^3-4\sqrt{a^3b^3})\leq0,$$ which is smooth.

We can rewrite this solution by the AM-GM's stile of course.